# How does ARC deal with tree data structures when the weak parent reference is deallocated

Tags: ios, swift, data-structures, tree

I am using a tree data structure. It has a parent and an array of childs.

```
class Hierarchy {
 var children: [Hierarchy] 
 weak var parent: Hierarchy?
}
```

I understand that if I do not make the parent as a weak reference, it will create strong reference cycles. But, doing this leads to deallocation of the parent in the middle of the tree.

Is there a solution/approach to have the reference to the parent alive while keeping a weak reference to it so that strong reference cycles are not created ?

Comment: How can a parent in the middle of the tree be deallocated? That parent would be a child in another node.

Comment: "But, doing this leads to deallocation of the parent in the middle of the tree." This would be correct behaviour. If you want the parent to stay alive, hold a strong ref to it somewhere. If you want children to keep parents alive (which would be odd in itself, but perhaps there are some valid use cases), then the one way to model that is with strong references both up and down the tree. But at that point, it becomes your job to manually `nil` out the references to break cycles. Getting that wrong would leave the strong reference cycles intact for longer than you need, causing a memory leak.

Answer (score 4):

It is not the child that keeps parent alive it is parent that keeps children alive.

Parent being weak reference is correct choice. The root reference that holds first instance in the hierarchy will keep that whole hierarchy alive.

```
// this initial reference will keep the whole hierarchy alive
var root = Hierarchy()
```

If the parent is released so will be its children.

```
// this will release the whole hierarchy
root = nil
```

When you start adding children that root node will keep those children alive:

```
var root = Hierachy()
var child = Hierarchy()
child.parent = root
root.children.append(child)
// child will still be alive as it is part of the root instance
child = nil
```

But if you remove some child from the hierarchy and release it, the whole branch coming from that child will be released.

Comment: `child = nil` will not release the child, its still in children array

Comment: @vignesh This is exactly what comment above that line says.

Comment: Thank you @DalijaPrasnikar. Keeping the initial reference keeps the whole hierarchy alive.